# How do I create a channel and server token using AgoraRtcEngineKit in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, api, token, agora.io

I am following the Agora.io [channel management guide](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/multiple_channel_apple?platform=iOS) for joining a channel using AgoraRtcEngineKit for iOS. It states that I should call `createRtcChannel` of the AgoraRtcEngineKit class to create an `AgoraRtcChannel` object with a channel ID. However, AgoraRtcEngineKit does not have a `createRtcChannel` method in Swift. The alternative is that I use Obj-C code, but this seems a little hacky.

Second, following the [token generation reference](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/token_server?platform=CPP), I need to generate a server token using RtcTokenBuilder. It states "your token needs to be generated on your own server, hence you are required to first deploy a token generator on the server." Ideally, I would be able to generate a token in Swift, but the only available languages for the source code is C++, Java, Python, PHP, Node.js, Go, Ruby. I assume I can do this with JavaScriptCore, but, like with the channel generation, this doesn't seem like an optimal solution.

Per the documentation:

- After a token (or a temporary token) is generated, the client should
  use the token to join a channel within 24 hours. Otherwise, you need
  to generate a new token (or temporary token).
- A token (or a temporary token) expires after a certain period of
  time. When the SDK notifies the client that the token is about to
  expire or has expired by the onTokenPrivilegeWillExpire or
  onTokenExpired callbacks, you need to generate a new token and call
  the renewToken method.
- The token encoding uses the standard HMAC/SHA1 approach and the
  libraries are available on common server-side development platforms,
  such as Node.js, Java, PHP, Python, and C++.

> What is the standard way to generate a channel and token to join channel using AgoraRtcEngineKit in iOS Swift via Agora.io?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the exact same question. If you find your answer on your own, would you mind posting it as well? Thanks

Comment: @Jaqueline I figured it out--you need to deploy the dynamic key token generation script on Heroku and parse the HTTP get request (see my answer below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ultimately figured it out following [this guide on deploying a Dynamic Key Server](https://medium.com/agora-io/2-click-setup-testing-token-server-b1c6fea9e1ad). You need to simply deploy a Heroku Dynamic Key server, which is in the TokenServer-nodeJS. Go to this deployment [link](https://dashboard.heroku.com/new?button-url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fagora-io%2F2-click-setup-testing-token-server-b1c6fea9e1ad&template=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FAgoraIO-Community%2FTokenServer-nodejs) and input your respective Agora.io `APP_ID` and `APP_CERTIFICATE`. Once the token server is deployed, we can use an HTTP get request to get the token as a response in JSON format which you can then parse with a framework like SwiftyJSON. Namely, once the server is running you replace  below with your instance url and generate tokens using this endpoint:
`https://<heroku url>/access_token?channel=test&uid=1234`

Using this instance url example:

```
let request = AF.request("https://matchr-token.herokuapp.com/access_token?channel=test&uid=1234")

request.responseJSON { (response) in

    guard let tokenDict = response.value as! [String : Any]? else { return }

    let token = tokenDict["token"] as! String

    // use the generated token here

 }
```

There are two parameters in this instance url, i.e. the `channel` and `uid`, which can be set as needed to generate a unique token.

Comment: I did what you said and I looked at your medium link. I generated a token link and http requested but when I use token that is taken from https://<myurl>/access_token?channel=test&uid=1234 it doenst work. When I use a temporary token from agora it works. Why doesn't work token that is taken from heroku. I use like that;  await _engine.joinChannel(token,channelId, null, 0);   should I change 0 to something else

Comment: I thought token has to be used but it doesn't. As I understand, it should be used for security so  I didn't use token. I write null instead of token and it worked